# Unable to push to Heroku after deleting (accidentally) and rebasing local repo (Git)

Tags: git, heroku

So, I accidentally deleted .git from my local repo, but luckily I had a remote to clone from. I cloned from my remote and was unable to push to it, so I did a rebased and `--forced` a push. Everything was back to normal.

Before I accidentally delete .git from my local repo, it was already associated with my Heroku app. I made some changes to my codebase and tried to `git push heroku master`, but got the following:

```
$ git push heroku master
error: Could not read 156fd03f52a859ff77509fd5928b12b951337ba4
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 80ccb34c51e769253a656c0d1471927b3a34bcc6
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to (my heroku remote)
```

I've tried `git push -f heroku master`, but got the same errors as above. I then tried to reset Heroku remote with `heroku repo: reset`, and it was successfully reset. I then tried to `git push heroku master` again after the reset and got the same errors.

Now I don't know what do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting fresh in another project directory
and `heroku login` there before doing any commits